# how to validate given data is alphanumeric or not with zend_validator

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have code

```
$this->addValidator('Regex', false, 
                     array('/^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/'));
```

which is used to validate if data is alphanumeric or not but its not working,

how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using standard Alnum validator for this purpose.

In form definition like this:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'username', array(
  'label' => 'Uživatelské jméno',
  'required' => true,
  'validators' => array(
      array('Alnum'),
      array('StringLength', false, array(2, 50))
  )
));
```

In your notation something like following should do the trick:

```
$this->addValidator('Alnum');
```

See possible arguments/other standard valiators on on [Zend Framework pages](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex works fine, so is the validator. Just verify that you have used it in the correct place:

An example:

```
    $login = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('uesrlogin');
    $login->setLabel('Enter username :')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addValidator('Regex', false, array('/^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/'));
```

As @Kamil pointed out, using the  Zend_Validate_Alnum validator will be the best bet to check alphanumerics. It even adds multi language support to your project.

> When using Zend_Validate_Alnum then the language which the user sets
>   within his browser will be used to set the allowed characters. This
>   means when your user sets de for german then he can also enter
>   characters like ä, ö and ü additionally to the characters from the
>   english alphabet.

Comment: What worked for me is:

[a-zA-Z]*  it allows alphabetic only

[a-zA-Z0-9]*  it allows  alphabetic and numerical value only

[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*  it allows alphabetic ,numeric and blank spaces

Comment: If either of the two answers helped you or guided you to the right answer, tick the answer